# Select a node with its children based on its class, and turn it into an object

Tags: html, node.js, cheerio

I want to find out how to scrape website data. This is a part of the html that I am interested in. I am using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for finding the data I need.

```
<td class="col-item-shopdetail">
    <div class="shoprate2 text-right hidden-xs">
        <div class="currbox-amount">
            <span class="item-searchvalue-curr">SGD</span>
            <span class="item-searchvalue-rate text-black">42.0000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inverserate">TWD 100 = SGD 4.2</div>
        <div class="rateinfo">
            <span class="item-timeframe">12 hours ago</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shopdetail text-left">
        <div class="item-shop">Al-Aman Exchange</div>
        <div class="item-shoplocation">
            <span class="item-location1"><span class="icon icon-location3"></span>Bedok</span>
            <span class="item-location2"><span class="icon iconfa-train"></span>Bedok                            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I wish to make "col-item-shopdetail" class as an object and store all class with name "col-item-shopdetail" into an array for access.

So if possible, it will be access like array.item-inverserate or through cheerio selector like

```
$('.col-item.shopdetail').children[0].children[0].children[1]
```

I have tried looping through the names of shop and store in an array and use another loop after finish looping the names to find the rates. Then try and match the rates to the name by access same index of the array. However this did not work for unknown reason where each time the rate printed is of different value and index of the same name are different in each try.

This is close to what I want but it does not work:

[how to filter cheerio objects in `each` with selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381891/how-to-filter-cheerio-objects-in-each-with-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you want an array of objects representing elements having class `.col-item-shopdetail` and each of those objects should have a property corresponding to the `.item-inverserate` element they contain ?

You need the [map method](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#map-functionindex-element-)

```
my_array = $('.col-item-shopdetail').map(function(i, el) {
    // Build an object having only one property being the .item-inverserate text content
    return {
       itemInverserate: $(el).find('.item-inverserate').text()
    }; 
}).get();

// You can also directly target inverserate nodes 
// which will exclude empty entries ('shopdetail' that have no 'inverserate')
// Loop over .item-inverserate elements found
// somewhere in a .col-item-shopdetail
// (beware, space matters)
my_array = $('.col-item-shopdetail .item-inverserate').map(function(i, el) {
    // Build an object having only one property being the .item-inverserate text content
    return {itemInverserate: $(el).text()};

    // Note: If all you need is the inverserate value,
    // Why not avoiding an intermediate full object?
    // return $(el).text()
}).get();
```

Since Cheerio developers have built their API based on jQuery with most of  the core methods, we can simply test snippets in the browser ...

```js
my_array = $('.col-item-shopdetail').map(function(i, el) {
    return {
       itemInverserate: $(el).find('.item-inverserate').text()
    }; 
}).get();

console.log(my_array[0].itemInverserate)

my_array_2 = $('.col-item-shopdetail .item-inverserate').map(function(i, el) {
    // Build an object having only one property being the .item-inverserate text content
    return {itemInverserate: $(el).text()};
}).get();

console.log(my_array_2[0].itemInverserate)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table><tr><td class="col-item-shopdetail">
    <div class="shoprate2 text-right hidden-xs">
        <div class="currbox-amount">
            <span class="item-searchvalue-curr">SGD</span>
            <span class="item-searchvalue-rate text-black">42.0000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inverserate">TWD 100 = SGD 4.2</div>
        <div class="rateinfo">
            <span class="item-timeframe">12 hours ago</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shopdetail text-left">
        <div class="item-shop">Al-Aman Exchange</div>
        <div class="item-shoplocation">
            <span class="item-location1"><span class="icon icon-location3"></span>Bedok</span>
            <span class="item-location2"><span class="icon iconfa-train"></span>Bedok                            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```